# OpenGL ES 2.0 spamming log with 'unable to find phys addr ...'

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I am using this fragment shader

```
// Pixel shader Gouraud Shading - Per-vertex lighting

precision mediump float;

// texture variables
uniform sampler2D texture1; // color texture

varying float tex;
varying vec2 tCoord;

// the color
varying vec4 color;

void main() {
    if(tex==0.0)
    gl_FragColor=color;
    else {
    gl_FragColor=texture2D(texture1, tCoord);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for textured models. But if i render models without textures, my log is spammed by following line every frame

> Unable to find phys addr for 204b70

When i comment out the else part in fs, there are no error logs. I checked the value of tex in fs by color method and it was 0.0.
Any suggestion?

Comment: what do you mean by "render models without textures" ?